# Android Development With Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Qt says about producing an IDE for Android developement, Will that IDE use C++ language for coding or Java? And i have read on internet about some bugs in that IDE? Have those bugs being removed?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for [necessitas](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about [Lighthouse](http://code.google.com/p/android-lighthouse/). In Lighthouse user writes his app in C++, compile it and then deploy on Android. The important note is that Qt librares are needed on Android device. These libs are downloaded from market at the first run of Lighthouse app.

IDE used to do it is standard Qt Creator.